# PyGtk : destroying combobox causes error

Tags: python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

My aim is to destroy a combobox if one of its items is active.

I wrote this test code :

```
import pygtk
pygtk.require('2.0')
import gtk
import gobject

def remove(combobox):
  if 'OptionC' in combobox.get_active_text():
    combobox.destroy()

window = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
window.set_default_size(800, 600)
window.set_title("Test")
window.connect("destroy", gtk.main_quit)
main_box = gtk.VBox(False, 2)
window.add(main_box)
nb = 3
for i in range(nb):
  liststore = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING)
  combo = gtk.ComboBox(liststore)
  cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
  combo.pack_start(cell, True)
  combo.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)
  for text in ["OptionA-%d"%(i+1), "OptionB-%d"%(i+1), "OptionC-%d"%(i+1)]:
    combo.append_text(text)
    combo.set_active(0)
  combo.connect("changed", remove)
  main_box.pack_start(combo, expand=False)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

If I open the popup of the combobox and click to select "OptionC", I have this message :

```
combo.py:29: Warning: invalid unclassed pointer in cast to `GObject' gtk.main()
combo.py:29: Warning: g_object_notify: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed gtk.main()
combo.py:29: Warning: g_object_set: assertion `G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed gtk.main()
```

But if I select "OptionC" just scolling the combobox (without opening the popup), no error is encountered.

Thanks for your advice!

**Answer : (working for pygtk version 2.24 but NOT for 2.16)**

Replace this block :

```
liststore = gtk.ListStore(gobject.TYPE_STRING)
combo = gtk.ComboBox(liststore)
cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
combo.pack_start(cell, True)
combo.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)
```

By this function :

```
combo = gtk.combo_box_new_text()
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but there is a subtle bug: you are making three signal connections for each combobox; move the `combo.connect()` call to outside the inner `for` loop so `changed` is only connected once.

Comment: You're right. It was useless to connect three times each combobox and I corrected this. Unfortunately, that's not the cause of the error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes because you use a liststore.
New gtk code should now use `combo_box_new_text()`

here is your code working :

```
for i in range(nb):
  combo = gtk.combo_box_new_text()
  cell = gtk.CellRendererText()
  combo.pack_start(cell, True)
  combo.add_attribute(cell, 'text', 0)
  for text in ["OptionA-%d"%(i+1), "OptionB-%d"%(i+1), "OptionC-%d"%(i+1)]:
    combo.append_text(text)
    combo.set_active(0)
  combo.connect("changed", remove)
  main_box.pack_start(combo, expand=False)
window.show_all()
gtk.main()
```

Comment: No, your proposal doesn't work better... Moreover, according [the documentation](http://www.pygtk.org/pygtk2reference/class-gtkcombobox.html), `combo_box_new_text()` is equivalent to my code.

Comment: My code works fine here and solves your issue. I use  gtk.pygtk_version
(2, 24, 0)

Comment: I used gtk.pygtk_version (2, 16, 0). I tested with (2, 24, 0) and you're right, no error occurs. Thanks for your help! No idea for the version 2.16 ?

Comment: Sorry Pierre, I have no machine still running 2.16 and can't test that easily. Happy it works for you with 2.24 !

Comment: The use of GtkListStore should not make a difference. If there was a bug in GTK+ 2.16 that was fixed later, that would answer it, but at this point it's too late for even GTK+ 2.anything (and I don't know if this kind of bug would be an exception that would still get a bugfix anymore). Glad it works now, in whatever case!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is solid, the widgets are destroyed like they should be. Just write it off as an oddity of pygtk/PyGObject's memory management.

Comment: pygtk != pygobject. This is using the former.

Comment: I have ported this code to pygobject2 and it yields the same error. I've put both of them in the answer on purpose.

Comment: That's very suspicious then; if it's a bug in both PyGTK and python-gobject then either something happens to be wrong with both of them or there's a bug in GTK+...

Comment: It could very well be true. After researching further, I found out that the bug occurs only on the first "changed" signal call. Making the slot a no-op with the like of `if (first) { first = false; return; } else {...}` does not yield any errors on second call.

Comment: No, the bug doesn't occur only on the first "changed" signal call. For example, if you select firstly "OptionB" ("changed" signal is emitted) and then "OptionC", the bug still occur.
I could note that no bug occurs on the last combobox created.

Answer (score 0):

So why are you not using

`combobox.hide()`

instead of

`combobox.destroy()`

It seems destroying individual widgets is not really the thing you should do. In most cases I do not destroy Gtk widgets, since later you may wish to show them again.